# A two-dimensional integral related to a Gaussian distribution

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$I=\int_a^b\int_a^b\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\theta}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2\theta^2}}dxdy$.

With the aid of Mathematica software, the result is

$I=\left(e^{-\frac{(a-b)^2}{2\theta^2}}-1\right)\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\theta+(a-b)\,\text{Erf}\left(\frac{a-b}{\sqrt2\theta}\right)$

where $\text{Erf}(\bullet)$ is error function.

Anyone has idea about detailed derivation of this result?

Comment: The $x$-integral can be evaluated in terms of the [error function $\text{Erf}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). The second integral then becomes the integral of $\text{Erf}$. This can be evaluated by using integration by parts (take $v'=1$ and $u = \text{Erf}$).

Comment: @Winther, thank you for your suggestion. I try to do it by your suggestion, but I can't get the same results as Mathematica's. I think it is due to my fault. So can you leave a detailed derivation for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing to do is to derive the integral: $\int \text{Erf}(x){\rm d}x = x\cdot \text{Erf}(x) + \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} + C$. If you managed to prove this then it's just a matter of being very careful and performing some simple substitutions to get the integral(s) on a form where you can use this result. One have to be careful, it's very easy to do mistakes as there are several substitutions that has to be done. If you have done the derivation and want it checked just add it to the question and I'll be happy to go through it and see if I can find any mistakes.

Comment: $\int\text{Erf}(x)dx=x\text{Erf}(x)-\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: I don't think so, the expression I have above is correct (atleast if we use the 'standard' definition of Erf as given on Wiki). Doing integration by parts the final integral is $-\int x \cdot \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}\right]{\rm d}x = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} + C$ where we can solve the integral using a $t = -x^2 \to {\rm d}t = -2x{\rm d}x$ substitution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I will go on the derivation and will let you know if I get the right result this time.

Comment: @Winther, that is just the mistake I made. And now I got exactly the same results as Mathematica's. Many thanks.

Comment: Good! If you feel like it consider writing up your own answer. Then this question has an answer and you can get credit for it (you can also accept it if no better answer comes in).

Comment: I write up my own answer at the place where I posted the question. BTW, How to accept an answer?

Comment: Your derivation looks good, just a small typo: there is an $\ell$ where it should be $t$ in $x=\sqrt{2}\theta t + y$. To be able to accept it is needs to be posted as an answer below.

Comment: @Winther, thanks for pointing out the samll typo. The answer is posted blow as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Winther's suggestion, I successfully have the results as follows:
$\frac{{\left( {x - y} \right)}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }} = t \Rightarrow x = \sqrt 2 t \theta  + y\\
 = \int_a^b {\left( {\int_{\frac{{b - y}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}}^{\frac{{b - y}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \theta }}{e^{ - {t^2}}}\sqrt 2 \theta dt} } \right)} dy\\
 = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b {\left( {{\rm{Erf}}\left( {\frac{{b - y}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} \right) - {\rm{Erf}}\left( {\frac{{a - y}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} \right)} \right)} dy\\
{\rm{ = }}\frac{1}{2}\left[ {\sqrt 2 \theta \left. {\left( {u{\rm{Erf}}\left( u \right) + \frac{{{e^{ - {u^2}}}}}{{\sqrt \pi  }}} \right)} \right|_0^{\frac{{b - a}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} + \sqrt 2 \theta \left. {\left( {u{\rm{Erf}}\left( u \right) + \frac{{{e^{ - {u^2}}}}}{{\sqrt \pi  }}} \right)} \right|_0^{\frac{{a - b}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}}} \right]\\
 = {\left( {{e^{ - {{\left( {\frac{{b - a}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} \right)}^2}}} - 1} \right)\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }} \theta  + \left( {b - a} \right){\rm{Erf}}\left( {\frac{{b - a}}{{\sqrt 2 \theta }}} \right)}$