# How do I solve this quadruple integral that involves gaussian like terms?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$$
\int_{x} \int_{y} \int_{z} \int_{w} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left\|\left(\begin{array}{l}
y-x \\
z-y \\
y-z
\end{array}\right)\right\|^{2}\right) d x d y d z d w
$$

I tried writing it as
$$
\int_{x} \int_{y} \int_{z} \int_{w} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(z-y)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(w-z)^{2}\right) d x d y d z d w
$$

and splitting this into
$$
\int_{x} \int_{y} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{2}\right) \int \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(z-y)^{2}\right) \int_{w} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(w-z)^{2}\right) d w d z d y d x
$$

And then moving out all of these as gaussians, but it seems that at the end I'm left with

$$
2 \pi \int_{x} d x
$$

So does this integral not converge? Or did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: It seems you did a typo. Check it please. (w, y or which one?)

Comment: I would consider the map $$(x,y,z,w)\mapsto (x,y-x,z-y,w-z)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthew H. suggested and following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833331/a-two-dimensional-integral-related-to-a-gaussian-distribution), let $u:=(w-z)/\sqrt{2}$, $t:=(z-y)/\sqrt{2}$ and $s:=(y-x)/\sqrt{2}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_x \int_y \int_z \int_w &\exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{2}\right] \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(z-y)^{2}\right] \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(w-z)^{2}\right] \mathrm{d}w \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2^{3/2}\int_x\int_s\int_t\int_u \exp\left(-s^2\right) \exp\left(-t^2\right) \exp\left(-u^2\right) \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}(s) + c_1\right]\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}(t) + c_2\right]\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}(u) + c_3\right] + c_4 \\
&= x\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + c_1\right]\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{z-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + c_2\right]\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{w-z}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + c_3\right] + c_4,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). If you integrate over the reals, you will end up with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} &\exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{2}\right] \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(z-y)^{2}\right] \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}(w-z)^{2}\right] \mathrm{d}w \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2^{3/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \exp\left(-s^2\right) \exp\left(-t^2\right) \exp\left(-u^2\right) \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}x \\
&= (2\pi)^{3/2}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}x,
\end{aligned}
$$
whose integral clearly diverges.